# Objective C: SetNeedsDisplay

Tags: objective-c, timer

I've been reading this book on game programming, but the examples are not that great. I'm working on one that calls `[self setNeedsDisplay]` but it cause the app the crash.

This is all the code I have, copied verbatim from the book:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
//start timer that will fire every second
[car setAlpha:0];
[road setAlpha:0];
currentImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"road.png"];

//start timer that fires every second
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

//start timer that fires every hundreth of a second
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.01) target:self selector:@selector(onTimerRoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)onTimerRoad
{   
    int tileIndex;
tileIndex += 1;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)onTimer {
[self update];
[self draw];
}

-(void)update {
[self updateRoad];
}

-(void)updateRoad {
[self randomRoadUpdate];
}

-(void)randomRoadUpdate {
int distance = (random() % 11) -5;
CGPoint oldPosition = road.center;
if (oldPosition.x + distance < 96 || oldPosition.x + distance > 224)
    return;
road.center = CGPointMake(oldPosition.x + distance, oldPosition.y);
}

-(void)draw {

}

- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    //init code
}
return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGImageRef image = CGImageRetain(currentImage.CGImage);
CGRect imageRect;
imageRect.origin = CGPointMake(160, 240);
imageRect.size = CGSizeMake(320.0, 480.0);
CGContextRef uiContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToRect(uiContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
CGContextDrawTiledImage(uiContext, imageRect, image);

}
```

Comment: Any further information than "causes the app to crash"? Do you get an exception? Do you have backtrace? Have you tried anything to debug?

Comment: Anything interesting in `Console.app`?

Comment: All the console says is it received the signal SIGABRT. All I did for debugging was remove that line and it worked properly. I'm not too sure what it does other than update the display? The book isn't very clear

Comment: Do you see an EXC_BAD_ACCESS anywhere? currentImage is being released, and I think the crash is occurring on currentImage.CGImage because of this. If you add NSZombiesEnabled=YES to the environment, you should get an error telling you this.

Comment: I took out the line with currentImage.CGImage and another one related to it but it still crashed with SIGABRT

Comment: Oh there's a warning that says MainViewController may not respond to [self setNeedsDisplay]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out instead of `[self setNeedsDisplay]` I need to do `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]`